# Android emulator doesn't use Windows host file?

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator

[m3 http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/461/65254534.jpg](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/461/65254534.jpg)

Chrome using the windows' HOST file:

[m1 http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9380/59750633.jpg](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9380/59750633.jpg)

Android emulator:

[m2 http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/7363/19470766.jpg](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/7363/19470766.jpg)

**edit**

"On Windows, the emulator obtains the addresses by calling the GetNetworkParams() API. Note that this usually means that the emulator ignores the content of your "hosts" file (/etc/hosts on Linux/OS X, %WINDOWS%/system32/HOSTS on Windows)."

how can I use static IPs in the emulator?

Comment: Looks like you already have your answer.

Comment: I'd like to know how to make it work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, it's *not* possible to change the phone's own `/etc/hosts` file within the emulator - it's on a read-only file system.

Personally, I'd run a local resolving server on your PC, point your Windows O/S at that, and then override the entries properly.

[Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) will do the job, and has a nice feature to allow you to insert "local data" into your DNS results.

Answer (score 4):

I got this article, it explains how to edit the hosts file. I don't know if it works yet, bit it might help.

BROKEN (Feb 2015) - http://www.bradcurtis.com/2011/02/13/hosts-file-google-android-emulator/ (Leaving it in case it recovers)

If I'm not wrong, they moved the link [here](http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/), I'm not sure if it's the same article, I haven't touched this since may 2012.
http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/ (Mirror Link https://web.archive.org/web/20180615121728/http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/)

---

EDIT: Adds a new link that works and talks about the ame issue (Not sure if it's the same article.

Comment: This is probably the easiest to do with minimal setup, and uses only tools provided in the Android SDK.

Comment: broken link [15 chars]

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I updated the url. Not sure if it's the same thou :(

Comment: Mirror https://web.archive.org/web/20180615121728/http://www.bradcurtis.com/hosts-files-and-the-google-android-emulator/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to update the Android phone's own hosts file with:

```
adb remount
adb push hosts /etc/system/hosts (most tutorials suggest this file)
adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts (some VM systems seem to prefer this file instead!, for me this worked)
```

if any issues like i kept randomly getting a 'read-only file system' error 90
% of the time I tried running above, then try running '**adb root**' before above (didnt work for me through), or start the Android VM manually with your android sdk's emulator.exe:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6_API_23 -partition-size 512
```

(some peeps recommended making partition size manually so can write to the VM easier?, eh seemed to work better but still got random read-only errors still).
An Android VM created with GenyMotion seemed much stabler and never get 'read only file system' issues with their VMs when i tried pushing the hosts file.

If the website you want to look at is hosted on your host machine, then you can point to it via a special IP android VMs recognize as the host machine via the hosts file:

```
10.0.2.2 test-drupal8.localhost
```

or if using Bridged Networking instead of NAT (pretend your windows host machine is 172.16.6.50 where your website is hosted and Android VM is 172.16.6.51), then can use windows ip directly:

```
172.16.6.50 test-drupal8.localhost
```

Note: make sure Windows Firewall/antivirus/firewalls are off if testing as they were blocking my urls until i turned them off.

Comment: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/etc/system/hosts': secure_mkdirs failed: Read-only file system