# Mac lion can't connect to Socket when use Android emulator

Tags: macos, sockets, android-emulator, emulation

When I use Windows to run eclipse Android emulator to connect socket,it was successful.
However, when I use Mac os lion to run the "Same" code ,the emulator shows"unfortunately
client test was stop!!"please help me solve this.And I already add the permission to internet!

```
package com.example.testclientokok;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        Socket socket=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8888);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

server part

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MyServer {

 public static void main(String[] args){
 ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
 Socket socket = null;
 DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

 try {
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
  System.out.println("Listening :8888");
 } catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

while(true){
  try {
   socket = serverSocket.accept();
   dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
   dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
   System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
   dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
  finally{
   if( socket!= null){
    try {
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataInputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataInputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}

if( dataOutputStream!= null){
 try {
  dataOutputStream.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I know at one point I had to setup a dns server for the emulator (see the comment below the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4859396/530933)).  I would think this problem stems from a setting within eclipse rather then the os.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are executing MyServer on your machine, where you also run the emulator. If the Activity running in the emulator wants to establish a connection with MyServer, then it should use the following IP address : **10.0.2.2** (and not localhost, which references the emualor loopback interface).

See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: I found the solution !!!
The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html