# Android emulator: Internet gets disconnected after running my app

Tags: android, emulation

I read many other Questions/Answers for this issue but cannot find the answer.
I am "NOT" having problem with proxy since Intenet works in the beginning.

Case1:
1. Launch emulator
2. Run browser & surf, surf, surf...
Result: Works fine!

Case2:
1. Launch emulator
2. Run browser & surf.
Result: Works fine!
3. Run my app
Result: internet stopped working
4. Run browser & surf.
Result: internet stopped working

So what am I doing in my app? Nothing much. 
But I open multiple internet connections to download images and others.

My app works perfectly on real devices.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse try:

**Window>Preferences>Android>Launch**

Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676073/android-emulator-dns-server-usage)